# How to suppress objectProperty in Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I've problem to suppress one objectProperty in graph on my fuseki server.
I tried to use many way to delete my objectProperty without results.

I tried to use s-delete to suppress:

```
./s-delete http://localhost:3030/ds 'DELETE {?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ds/dependsOfExchange> ?o}'
```

or

```
./s-delete http://localhost:3030/ds 'DELETE {GRAPH ?g {?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ds/dependsOfExchange> ?o} WHERE{?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ds/dependsOfExchange> ?o}}'
```

I tried to find some information about how to use correctly s-delete to suppress objectproperty or dataproperty in data stored in my fuseki server, but I haven't found anything useful. And there is no update or suppress tools accessible by the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "suppress" it?  Delete all the triples where it's a property?  If you've loaded an OWL ontology, you probably also want to delete the triples of which it's the subject or object (e.g., property declarations, and other axioms).

Answer (score 0):

`s-delete` executes part of the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol which operaes on whole graphs only.  It is an HTTP delete on a named graph.

To modify part of a graph, you need SPARQL Update, and so use `s-update`.

The delete command, using the `DELETE WHERE` short form might be:

```
DELETE WHERE {?s <http://www.semanticweb.org/ds/dependsOfExchange> ?o}
```

or the `GRAPH` version.